# remove time conversion in the column. Error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have time column that looks like the one that I attached below. How to remove +0600 conversion
I appreciate your help
I tried

```
clean['event_time_selected_timezone'] = clean['event_time_selected_timezone'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

But it gives Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values Error

Comment: First convert column to datetimes.

Comment: It gives this error Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: `clean['event_time_selected_timezone'] = pd.to_datetime(clean['event_time_selected_timezone'])` return error?

Comment: Yes, this error SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: There is some filtering in your code?

Comment: oh thank you. Now I don't have +0600, instead I have 2022-07-11 00:00:14.10400. How do I keep only 2022-07-11 00:00:14

Comment: try `clean['event_time_selected_timezone'] = clean['event_time_selected_timezone'].dt.tz_localize(None).dt.floor('S')`